# Displaying errors with settings api

Tags: settings-api

I'm not using the full settings api, just this code:

```
register_setting( 'my_options', 'my_options', 'my_options_validate' );
```

Then my validation:

```
  $options = get_option('my_options');

  if(error_found){

    add_settings_error( 'my_options', 'settings_updated', 'error_message_here', 'error');

  }

  return $options;
```

But on postback no errors are displayed. So my questions are:

does simply setting an error message result in its display?
do I have to use the full settings api to have errors displayed?
do I have do anything to disable the "settings updated" message on postback?

I've tried using settings_errors but no errors show.

Comment: Exactly what kind of errors are you hoping to show? Unless your setting error_found somewhere ( missing $? ) then Wordpress will simply return a WP_Error object or null on a call, or it'll output to the browser that the user has arrived somewhere they shouldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does simply setting an error message result in its display? do I have to use the full settings api to have errors displayed? do I have do anything to disable the "settings updated" message on postback?

You need to add a call to `settings_errors`, e.g.:

```
/**
 * Displays all messages registered to 'your-settings-error-slug'
 */
function your_admin_notices_action() {
    settings_errors( 'your-settings-error-slug' );
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'your_admin_notices_action' );
```

If you don't, then the errors you added will not be displayed. You may also want to check that `$error_found` is true. It is not a WP constant I recognise, so I assume it is part of your code ( and hasn't been set ) ( also, it's missing a `$` at the start? ).

There is also the possibility that no errors have occurred, or that your validation is allowing invalid cases to pass through.

Comment: Thanks, Tom. error_found is pseudo code standing in for a real error. I'm also wondering how I can cancel the normal save settings process if I find errors?

Comment: I don't know if you can other than possibly a wp_redirect followed by a die(), but that sounds terribly hackish

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was developing my ArticleForge WordPress plugin.  I did not want to allow erroneous input to enter the database, but yet I wanted to give the user a chance to correct their input.  So, after much creative process, I did devise a method that works.  You don't have to do a wp_redirect or a die().  The main gist of it is that you switch out the users input during validation with that of the existing options and return those values instead.

You can check out [my blog post](http://www.bytewisemcu.org/article/robust-settings-flow/) for a detailed description of the process I followed.

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer. A good answer should not rely on an external link.

Comment: I realized that but it's a huge chunk of text spanning multiple pages.

Comment: @Borgboy And the link doesn't even work now.